# ItemsControl.ItemTemplate with multiple DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a FlipVIew with pages that can be scrolled horizontally. 
Each page holds a ScrollViewer(vertical scroll) with an ItemsControl. The itemsControl holds an itemTemplate which is a row (each page holds rows of data).

`I want to change the template of a row at some button click`. Now I have 1 type of row, but I want to implement another 2 types but don't know how...basically the current row type is defined via DataTemplate and I want to define another 2 DataTemplates and bind the dataTemplate to the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="RowItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding OptionsPageVisibility}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:Name="RowType1">
               <Grid x:Name="OptionItemGrid" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <!-- here is the content of the rowType1 -->                  
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
            <!--<DataTemplate x:Name="RowType2">  --- I want just 1 of these 3 data to be my item template
            </DataTemplate x:Name="RowType2">
            <DataTemplate x:Name="RowType3">
            </DataTemplate x:Name="RowType3"> -->
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Where is `RowItemsControl` declared and which part do you not know how to do?

Comment: RowItemsControl is an ItemsControl - it is bind to some ObservableCollection which holds an array of data. Now I have 1 DataTemplate inside  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>. How can I define another 2 DataTemplates(with other look of course) and choose 1 of these 3 dataTemplates to be the content of <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> ?

Comment: @Sheridan - Please see my post again (I've put some edit in it (in xaml))

Comment: I want each DataTemplate to have it's Gui and when the user is pressing a button to change the data template (the gui for the row)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to define your `DataTemplate` objects in the `Resources` section... it's even OK to use your `ItemsControl.Resources`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="RowItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding OptionsPageVisibility}">
      <ItemsControl.Resources>
           <DataTemplate x:Name="RowType1">
               <Grid x:Name="OptionItemGrid" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="RowType2">
                ...
            </DataTemplate x:Name="RowType2">
            <DataTemplate x:Name="RowType3">
                ...
            </DataTemplate x:Name="RowType3">
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
   </ItemsControl>
```

Next, you need to access and set this from the `Resources`, maybe in a `Button.Click` handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTemplate rowType2DataTemplate = RowItemsControl.FindResource("RowType2") as 
        DataTemplate;
    if (rowType2DataTemplate != null) RowItemsControl.ItemTemplate = 
        rowType2DataTemplate;
}
```

That should do the trick... let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was just in the middle of reading the UserControl.Resources stuff...this is very explicit for me...

Comment: WPF has a steep learning curve because it's so different. However, it's definitely worth persevering with... keep reading. :)